# How to print ASCII picture/logo in console using bash

Tags: bash, echo

I have a logo which I want to print/echo using bash in console, through scripts, but I can't even paste here properly(looks good inside .txt file):

```
 ___   _____ _   _  _____ _   _   ___
|  _| /  ___| | | ||  ___| \ | | |_  |
| |   \ `--.| |_| || |__ |  \| |   | |
| |    `--. \  _  ||  __|| .   |   | |
| |   /\__/ / | | || |___| |\  |   | |
| |_  \____/\_| |_/\____/\_| \_/  _| |
|___|                            |___|
```

How I can do that properly and make it colour without 3rd party extensions? 
Also, is it possible to print it from the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `tput`:

```
tput setaf 2; cat logo.txt
```

`2` is the color code here (red). These are the available codes:

```
Value   Color
0   Black
1   Red
2   Green
3   Yellow
4   Blue
5   Magenta
6   Cyan
7   White
8   Not used
9   Reset to default color
```

Comment: What about purple and cyan?

Comment: cyan is code 6. For purple use magenta: 5 (It's in the list above)

Comment: Sorry, long day. This is very interesting way! Could you please tell me more about this part: `"$(< logo.txt)"` . Why `""` and `$` are needed?

Comment: Nevermind. You don't really need them. Updated my answer

Comment: Both methods doesn't work in TravisCI :( works from iTerm. Text isn't coloured

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a travis account to test it. You may ask them for support.

Comment: Sure! Thanks, mate